# product of transvections is a transvection?

Tags: matrices, group-theory

In group theory and especially in the group $GL(n,F)$ we define for $i\neq j $ $X_{ij}(a) $to be the $n\times n$ matrix whose $(k,l)$ entry is equal to a if $(k,l)=(i,j)$ and equal to $\delta_{kl}$ otherwise . $X_{ij}$ is a subgroup of $GL(n,F)$ called the root subgroup. The matrices $X_{ij}(a)$ and their conjugates by elements of G are called transvection.

My question is: Is the product of transvections still a trasvection? Or simpler still, is $X_{ij}(a)X_{i'j'}(b)$ or generally $\prod_{i,j}X_{i,j}$ a transvection? If that doesn't hold, is there a weaker form of it that s true, for example if i=i'? I know for a fact that the root subgroups are conjugate to each other in $SL(n,F)$ but that doesn't seem to help much.

Comment: Observe that a transvection $\;X_{i,j}(a)\;$  is what we use in basic linear algebra to multiply *from the left* a matrix and its effect is to add to the $\;i-th\;$ row the $\;j-th\;$ row multiplied by $\;a\;$ , i.e.: it is an elementary operation on the rows of the multiplied matrix.

Comment: Please do explain **clearly** what exactly is that root group $\;X_{ij}\;$ ...all the transvections, or maybe all the transvections with **fixed** $\;i,j\;$ ...?

Comment: @DonAntonio   The root subgroup is $\{X_{ij}(a) : a\in F$} for i,j fixed. Transvections are all those matrices which can be written as $g X_{ij}(a) g^{-1}$  where $a\in F$, $g\in GL(n,F)$ and  $i\neq j$ (not fixed). I am referring to all the transvections for all i and j not just for a fixed pair. However the root subgroups are conjugate to each other, thus if it holds for a single pair , then it holds for every i and j. I am aware of the operations of $X_{ij}$ that you mentioned as well as a bunch of other properties but i cannot see how that helps in what I m asking.

Comment: With $n=2$, $X_{12}(1)X_{21}(1) = \left(\begin{array}{cc}2&1\\1&1\end{array}\right)$ is not a transvection.